# Rails: Route path based on object attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

This is my route

```
resources :programs
```

My Model is **Program**
which have one attribute **type**, that could be equal to "movie", or "tv_show".

- type = Movie
- type = TV Show

I would that If a program is a movie, the url will be:

```
http://example.com/movie/12
```

otherwise

```
http://example.com/tv_show/12
```

Is that possible?

I found this, but I don't know how to make dynamic (switched by object's attributes)

```
resources :programs, path: 'tv_show'
```

I'd want to avoid edit every program_url(p), I'm looking for a smart way **using routes.rb**

Answer (score 3):

Rails polymorphic_path might help.

```
movie = Movie.find(12)
polymorphic_path([movie]) #will give http://example.com/movie/12
tv_show = TvShow.find(12)
polymorphic_path([tv_show]) #will give http://example.com/tv_show/12
```

You can try this in your rails console as

> app.polymorphic_path([movie])

Comment: Thanks. But I have only one Model, that is Program (question updated)

Comment: Probably you can define separate routes for both movie and tv_show as      `resources :movie, controller: programs`                                 `resources :tv_show, controller: programs`                                In your views, you can then call different paths based on type.